# How to get all the tables from html table and create an object in jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I am working on this thing where I would need all the values from the html table and need to create an Object out of it and send to servlet.Is there any easy way to do it.I think of an approach where in I would send the whole table and then through jquery will access it but it may take time.Any better way would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Creating jsp is a process containing following steps (not exactly, but similar):

- Create Object
- Put it in the session
- Get data from session onto the jsp
- Translate jsp into servlet
- Convert Servlet into html response
- **Send response to the client**

The last step is where client could see information and makes decision. Usually user (from client side) submits a form or sends data through... let's say ajax channel. If you know JQuery, then you know javascript, and ajax isn't even a challenge for you.

Never mix **client-side** approach with **server-side** approach. Use *ajax, javascript* features to send data to the server side.

At the **server-side** from gathered information create whatever object you want.